# Tethering using bluetooth via Galaxy Nexus to Galaxy Tab 7(P1000) tablet

Tags: bluetooth, samsung-galaxy-nexus, samsung-galaxy-tab, tethering

Here is the point there is a secured WiFi connection - which password I don't know - but there is an device - Galaxy Nexus smartphone which is already connected to that WiFi and my Galaxy Tab tablet. 
There is any change to set GN as Bluetooth modem, to tether WiFi connection, for Galaxy Tab?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android 4.0+ officially supports bluetooth tethering in both directions (and allows bridging to whatever the internet connection is (wifi/usb/3G)).

You need:

- 1x device as tether host running Android 4.0+ that has wifi/3g/usb internet
- 1x client device running Android 4.0+
- both devices are bluetooth paired
- enabled 'bluetooth tethering' setting on the host device:
  settings => wireless & networks: more => tethering & portable hotspot => bluetooth tethering

You then can connect to the tethering profile:
settings => bluetooth => paired devices/GN => profiles/Internet Access

The GNexus fulfills all of that, however your P1000 cannot officially upgraded to Android 4.0 though, so you're out of luck or you have to install an aftermarket firmware (e.g. [CyanogenMod9](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Tab_%28GSM%29), which is based on Android 4.0.4)

Comment: Officially: yes. If you however install CM9 (I did so on a colleague's P1000) you can have this feature. As a side effect you get a brand new Galaxy Tab (the look and feel of Android 4.0 on the P1000 is far superior to the original 2.3 Gingerbread installation). It however voids your warranty (well, the warranty period has passed anyway).